# Как в pandas сменить столбцы со строками местами?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть такая таблица в pandas.DataFrame:

```
                        BTC_AMP          BTC_ARDR         BTC_BCH
baseVolume          29.54147359      219.97693010   2031.83823823   
high24hr             0.00002005        0.00004794      0.09649999   
highestBid           0.00001777        0.00004776      0.08940708   
id                          160               177             189   
isFrozen                      0                 0               0   
last                 0.00001774        0.00004775      0.08952025   
low24hr              0.00001460        0.00003310      0.08000701   
lowestAsk            0.00001784        0.00004788      0.08952026   
percentChange        0.08368967        0.31651502      0.07894772   
quoteVolume    1735747.47629757  5371617.18104734  23310.00568905
```

Не могу найти документацию на тему того как сменить столбцы и строки местами, чтобы получилось таблица вида:

```
       baseVolume   high24hr  highestBid
BTC_1  1            1         1   
BTC_2  2            2         2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите транспонировать DataFrame:

```
In [12]: new = df.T

In [13]: new
Out[13]:
           baseVolume  high24hr  highestBid     id  isFrozen      last   low24hr  lowestAsk  percentChange   quoteVolume
BTC_AMP     29.541474  0.000020    0.000018  160.0       0.0  0.000018  0.000015   0.000018       0.083690  1.735747e+06
BTC_ARDR   219.976930  0.000048    0.000048  177.0       0.0  0.000048  0.000033   0.000048       0.316515  5.371617e+06
BTC_BCH   2031.838238  0.096500    0.089407  189.0       0.0  0.089520  0.080007   0.089520       0.078948  2.331001e+04
```

С фильтрацией:

```
In [25]: df.T.query("last > .0001")
Out[25]:
          baseVolume  high24hr  highestBid     id  isFrozen     last   low24hr  lowestAsk  percentChange   quoteVolume
BTC_BCH  2031.838238    0.0965    0.089407  189.0       0.0  0.08952  0.080007    0.08952       0.078948  23310.005689
```

**UPDATE:**

> `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'`
>   как сконвертировать тип в запросе?

```
x = df.T
x.assign(last=pd.to_numeric(x.last, errors='coerce')).query("last > .0001")
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает, не подскажете также как отфильтровать строки по столбцу last>0.0001?

Comment: @ЕвгенийТимофеев, отфильтровать до поворота?

Comment: после, чтобы в данном примере осталась только последняя строка.
в df[df.last>0.00000100] df.last воспринимается как метод, а не как столбец

Comment: Спасибо, нажал бы ^, но рейтинга не хватает

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
как сконвертировать тип в запросе? Хотя тогда уж весь столбец

Comment: @ЕвгенийТимофеев, значит в ваших реальных данных встречаются строки ("не числа") в `last`